# Whether to incorporate zero inflation into model of binary variable on count variable?

Tags: count-data, zero-inflation

I have a dataset comprising two groups with 1 continuous covariate (ratio scale). The dependent variable is a count variable. The distribution of the dependent variable looks like this:

[image: Distribution of my variable of interest BY group]

I was wondering what the right model to analyze this dataset would be. I tried poisson, binomial, and negative binomial. For negative binomial, the Log Likelihood was closest to zero (or largest if you will). Therefore, I assume the negative binomial model is the best for my data (please correct me if I my reasoning is wrong).

**Should I try a model that incorporates zero inflation?**

Comment: I don't think you can compare log likelihoods from different models (ie Poisson vs Binomial vs Negative Binomial)...

Comment: @Glen: Can you help me understand why not?  Isn't the probability of the data given each model the likelihood of each model?  Or do you mean that you can't compare them without taking into account the prior probability of each model?

Comment: @NeilG It's like comparing AIC from a survival model to a logistic model, the likelihood functions are completely different.  Can't do it, not now, not ever.

Comment: @Glen:  But, isn't this is exactly how, for example, structure learning is done with Bayesian networks?  Each structure is a "different model" and one evaluates the likelihood of each model despite the likelihood functions being "completely different".  If you imagine the likelihood $f$, and the data as a point $x$, then what should the shape of $f$ matter?  The greater the height of $x$, the more likely the data is given the model, and so by Bayes' rule, the more likely the model given data.  All that's missing is a prior distribution over all models.

Comment: @NeilG That may be possible to what you're referring to, I'm not knowledgeable in that area.  And I should add that the Poisson is a special case of the negative binomial in which case comparing AICs is okay.  However, overall, when you switch the likelihood distributions log likelihoods are not comparable.

Comment: OK, wait, so now (in this specific case) I can compare the likelihoods of the different models (Poisson vs. Zero-inflated Poisson vs. Negative binomial Reg. vs. Zero-inflated Negative binomial reg)?

Comment: @Vincent To be safe, I would not compare the log-likelihoods.  With the Poisson vs NB model when you run the Poisson model you can see if the dispersion parameter is close to 1, if it is then fine, if not go with NB (and test whether the parameter is significant).  Zero-inflated models are completely different, what proportion are 0 counts?

Comment: proportion of zero counts: GROUP A: 1351/1580=~86%; GROUP B: 149/191=~78%; TOTAL: 1500/1771=~85%

Answer (score 3):

Zero-inflation (or any similar arbitrary additional degree of freedom) will probably increase the likelihood.  That's why if you're going to compare models, you should be using cross-validation to check how the validation error changes rather than just maximizing the likelihood on all of your data.

I once read that it's more convincing to reason about why a model theoretically fits data rather than just looking for low validation error.  It is easy to fool yourself into thinking that you have a good model.